# Changing static value permanently

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) service running. When a service is called, sometimes the service has to start again and populate all the static values because I guess the webserver shuts down the service after period of inactivity. If it is called constantly, it stays active and all the values are populated. I have a static integer in that class that gets used by the service calls and I have that at 30 for example, but I sometimes set that static value using service call so that the new value is 20, but since the service gets deconstructed by the web server after a period of inactivity, the value is again initialized to 30. Is there a way to permanently set the 30 value to 20 when the WCF service gets constructed (static constructors) get called? Is there any better way to do this? I have 2-3 of these values that I want to change permanently whenever I want through a web service call.

Comment: Sounds like you need to use a database or similar storage medium on the WCF service for these values.

Comment: http://redis.io/ is excellent for this (light weight, persistent across sessions and servers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using the built in Settings static class

```
Settings.Default["StaticValue"] = "30";
Settings.Default.Save();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I doubt that this is thread-safe. `Settings` was designed for Windows Forms, which would usually only have a single thread at a time touching that code. Not so with WCF.

Answer (score 0):

Even without the restart, if you are only storing this value in memory it's not stored "permanently".  A database or similar would be great, but if you are not using a database for anything already, using one to store a single value seems like overkill.  What about writing to a file?